# Filtering line from text file in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have been tasked with creating a logon script that will logoff a users abandoned sessions. I have found this from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/259436) which looked like a promising start.

I have modified Microsoft's script and currently have this.

```
query session %username% >session.txt
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3," %%i in (session.txt) DO logoff %%i
del session.txt
```

This generates a session.txt like the following.

```
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
 rdp-tcp#66        someuser                  3  Active                      
>rdp-tcp#67        someuser                 12  Active
```

My script currently skips the first line, parses the two remaining lines and logs off the sessions by ID. I would like to change this behavior such that I only logoff the abandoned session(3) and not my current session(12). Can I identify and filter the line containing >?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need  a log file . this will just slow down your script:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 eol=>" %%a in ('query session %username%') do set "sessionToKill=%%a"
echo %sessionToKill%
```

`eol=>` will skip every line starting with `>` . You can put the logoff logic directly in the for loop instead of the `set`.

Comment: fyi, I pinged Mofi [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34395679#34395679) and he is helping with some cleanup. This comment auto-deleted after a while.